# Saving FILE * into the struct in C

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to open file in function that loads arguments and then save it into struct containing args for later use in other functions. However I cant seem to be able to save it properly (FILE *A,*B equals 0x0). Here's whan I've got so far:

```
struct Args
{
       int action;      /* holds action token (see teacts)*/
       int error;
       FILE *A,*B;      /* files containing matrixes*/
       int r,s;         /* start coordinates*/
       int power,dir;   /* used in some other function */
} Args;

void getArgs(int argc, char *argv[],struct Args * args)
{
....
testopen(argv[4],args->A);
....
}

int openFile (const char *arg, FILE *input)
{
        input = fopen(arg,"r");

        if (input == NULL)
                return (1);
        else
                return (0);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
     struct Args args = {.action = A_ERROR};
     getArgs(argc,argv,&args);
     ....
}
```

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you have used `args` more often for names :)

Comment: What errors do you get? Think you should show some more code,

Comment: I'm guessing the above is not the actual code because of `args` instead of `Args` in `main()` and `testopen()` instead of `openFile()` in `getArgs()`. Can we see actual, compilable code?

Comment: I actually get no errors from compiler, I just get NULL instead of pointer to stream. caps were wrong, sry about that.

Comment: Thank you all for replies, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are passed by value in `C`, like everything else. The line:

```
input = ....;
```

in `openFile` only changes the value of the local variable (argument) `input` in that function, it doesn't change `args->A`.

To fix that, you could:

- pass a pointer to `args` into `openFile`.

  ```
  int openFile (const char *arg, struct Args *args)
  {
      args->A = fopen(arg,"r");
      ...
  ```
- pass a pointer to `args->A` (making the argument a `FILE**`):

  ```
  int openFile (const char *arg, FILE **input)
  {
      *input = fopen(arg,"r");
      ...
  ```
- not pass a `FILE*` at all, but return one and do:

  ```
  args->A = openFile(argv[4]);
  ```

  Make sure you return `NULL` on error and you can do error checking in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems spring immediately to mind. The first is that you call `testopen` when you should clearly be calling `openFile` but I'm going to assume that's just a typo.

The second is more insidious. If you want to change the file pointer within `openFile`, you need to pass a pointer to it since parameters are pass by value. You may think you're passing a pointer but in fact you need a double-pointer since it's the *FILE pointer itself* you're trying to change, not what it points to.

In other words, you'll need something like:

```
int openFile (const char *arg, FILE **input) {
    *input = fopen( arg, "r");
    if (*input == NULL)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
:
rc = openFile (argv[4], &(args->A));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that your structure initialisator initialise all elements to 0:

```
struct args args = {.action = A_ERROR};
```

That means, your FILE *A,*B are getting values NULL. And thus you can't save any values in them. Try again with:

```
struct args args;
args.atction = A_ERROR;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
void getArgs(int argc, char *argv[],struct Args * args)
{
....
openFile(argv[4],&args->A);
....
}

int openFile (const char *arg, FILE **input)
{
        *input = fopen(arg,"r");

        if (*input == NULL)
                return (1);
        else
                return (0);
}
```